# APPLE IOS Notification with .NET

Tags: .net, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am new to APPLE Push Notifications.I have p12 file,password and device token also.
I used code from https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp
But when i try to run it it will not show any error messages but the iphone does nt get any message.

Another code i have taken from http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/ but when i try to run this i am getting below error in log file.
**An error occurred while reading Apple response for token c5f4af5a1288c666666666668b3faff3b3f2f88d31cb1328873de3957d4555 - Input string was not in a correct format.**

Plz help me how to solve.

Comment: Do u think we have to test all your links? Please put the complete code here and explain your founds and issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the Redth APNS Sharp lib for this approach:

I think you are using a wrong proficency profile where push is not enabled. Did you get the message on app start "Would you allow push?"?

If not:

Make sure that you create an App Id that is push enabled. After the creation of the app id you have to create a new proficency profile and select the App Id where you enabled push. Download and install the new proficency profile.

Now select the push enabeld proficency profile in mono that is used for the app to run.